# Should I use property or private attribute?

Tags: python

Suppose I create a class:

```
class SomeClass:    
    def __init__(self, some_attribute):
        self._attribute = some_attribute

    @property
    def attribute(self):
        return self._attribute
```

Then, I add a method `new_method` to my object that will use the "attribute". 
Therefore, should I use `self._attribute` or `self.attribute`?:

```
def new_method(self):
    DoSomething(self.attribute) # or     DoSomething(self._attribute)
```

Does it make any impact or difference?

Comment: Use the property if you are going to have a property. But I wouldn't have a property to begin with in this case. Just a normal attribute

Comment: Why create a property an not use it? The overhead for normal business applications is 100% neglectable. If you call the property every microsecond we could start talking about performance. If you create a property then you do not want to access the raw value. This prevents you from getting the benefits of a property. That is decoupling of the internal data representation of your class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `self.attribute` will trigger a call to `SomeClass.attribute.__get__` and therefore come with more overhead.

Using `self._attribute` comes with less overhead but will introduce a bug in your code as soon as you add meaningful logic to the definition of `attribute`.

In my opinion, use `self.attribute` consistently. If the getter ever becomes a bottleneck, consider caching-strategies before using `_attribute` and `attribute` inside the class inconsistently. Sooner or later you will introduce a bug.

Comment: Wouldn't the `__get__()` overhead be negligible anyhow? I don't imagine the overhead is worth the headache possibly introduced by referencing a pre-processed private attribute when you actually need the post.

Comment: @Idlehands The overhead is negligible until you write it to do something complex. In principle there could be anything in there.

Answer (score 3):

My personal opinion is to use `self.attribute`. The reason is that how it is implemented may change.

Here it is stored as another instance variable, but it could be stored later in an underlying object for whatever reason.

This implementation will of course have a small overhead compared to the direct access.